# 'No Current record' error on tbl.Update after tbl.AddNew

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

I have this simple code:

```
Set tbl=DB.OpenRecordset("TableName",dbOpenTable)
tbl.AddNew
tbl("SomeField")=strSomeValue
tbl.Update
```

On the Update statement a no current record error is thrown.
I don't even understand how this can happen after the AddNew statement did not generate an error?!

Comment: Try this one: `tbl.Fields("SomeField")=strSomeValue`

Comment: Put a watch on tbl and put a break point at tbl.AddNew and debug. Browse the tbl watch to see what is going on.

Comment: Is that the whole method?  Can you post the whole method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can come to no other conclusion than that the table has become corrupt. I removed and rebuilt it and refilled it with data. The problem went away then (for now).

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is a simple answer, but do you definately have write permissions for the table in question, or perhaps have the DB reference open as read-only?  If either is true then Access can pass through the .Addnew but will fail at the point of commit (.Update) I only say this because your code seems to be fine.  If not then you can always try throwing a .MoveFirst in after opening your recordset to see if that also gives an error.